Creating separate table for each child entity in EF Core
I've recently stumbled into an issue in EF Core when I needed the parent entities to reference the child entities in one to many relationship. Since all parents are using the same child class and the IDs are represented by GUIDs, I've figured that I could use the same child table for all child entities in a following manner:
public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ParentBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children = new List<Child>();
}

public class Parent1 : ParentBase;
public class Parent2 : ParentBase;

This has proven to be problematic with EF Core as it causes foreign key constraint errors. Therefore I am currently looking a solution and to figure out how people normally solve the given problem. Naturally, I went ahead and created a separate child entity type for each object type like so:
public abstract class ChildBase;
public class Parent1Child : ChildBase;
public class Parent2Child : ChildBase;

public class ParentBase<T1>
    where T1 : ChildBase
{
    public List<T1> Children = new List<T1>();
}

public class Parent1 : ParentBase<Parent1Child>;
public class Parent2 : ParentBase<Parent2Child>;

This works (creates separate child tables), BUT it also introduces a generic and I don't enjoy the added complexity. There are dozen of such parent entities. Is there a way to refactor the code in a way that it still solves the initial problem but is easier to manage?

Can you provide a real-world example of such a relationship and how you end up with foreign key constraints with how you originally had it? I can't say I have ever encountered a situation where something like that would be necessary or beneficial. Relationships may vary depending on whether you are using TPH, TPT, or TPC for your parent-level inheritance.
